# Python script not executing second command when passing arguments with && operator in Bash script

Tags: python

I have a Bash script with the following content: `python "$@"`. When I pass the arguments `["-c", "print('First command')", "&&", "python", "-c", "print('Second command')"]` to the script, only the first command is executed, and the second command is not executed. Why is the second command not executed and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I would say the real question is: why do you have that bash layer (with all its escaping/quoting requirements that you've gotten wrong), when you can just call Python directly?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your command from,

```
["-c", "'print('First command')", "&&", "python", "-c", "print('Second command')"]
```

to,

```
["-c", "'print('First command')", "&&", "python", "-c", "'print('Second command')'"]
```

Added single quotes to command, how you did for the first working command.

**Update:**

**run_python.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

python "$@"
```

run command: `./dummy.sh -c 'print("hello")' && python -c 'print("world")'`

**output:**

```
hello
world
```

Comment: the result is：
The arguments were: -c 'print('First command') && python -c 'print('Second command')'

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    'print('First command')
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to remove the first quotas from the first command

```
["-c", "print('First command')", "&&", "python", "-c", "print('Second command')"]
```

or add escape symbol

```
["-c", "'print(\"First command\")'", "&&", "python", "-c", "'print(\"Second command\")'"]
```